# Why is Ray Tune track not saving all datapoints?

Tags: logging, ray

The following code block is meant to save multiple metrics from my current run:

```
track.log(pgd_loss=pgd_loss)
track.log(pgd_acc=pgd_acc)
track.log(test_loss=test_loss)
track.log(test_acc=test_acc)
```

However only the last line `track.log(test_acc=test_acc)` works.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to save all of your metrics with a single call:

```
track.log(pgd_loss=pgd_loss, pgd_acc=pgd_acc, test_loss=test_loss, test_acc=test_acc)
```

I suspect that `track.log` saves the values asynchronosly and by accident overwrites the values that the previous call to `track.log` has not yet finished saving.
That could be why only the last call works.

Comment: Nice! What version of Ray are you on? This should be fixed in the last few releases.

Comment: I'm using a very recent version.
I posted this answer before checking whether my solution actually worked, since it takes a long time for my script to run and I was pretty confident in my fix. The other scalars get logged and might have been logged before my changes, but only `test_acc` shows up in the tensorboard hparams section, which is why I though that only `test_acc` gets logged. I still have the same issue as before and can't get the other values to show up under hparams.

Comment: Here is how I got the other values to show up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855334/why-does-tensorboard-not-show-all-metrics/63855600#63855600

I don't think I should add this as another answer, since it doesn't seem to have any connection to Ray Tune.