# Why does tensorboard not show all metrics?

Tags: logging, tensorboard, ray

I'm using Ray Tune for hyperparameter optimization and logging.
Ray Tune successfully logs my scalar values and writes them to the Tensorboard log.

The values do show up in Tensorboards 'SCALARS' section, but in the 'HPARAMS' section, only `test_acc` shows up as a metric.

This is how I log the values:

```
track.log(pgd_loss=pgd_loss, pgd_acc=pgd_acc, test_acc=test_acc, test_loss=test_loss)
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to restart tensorboard.
Tensorboard seems to have an issue reliably detecting new scalar values for the 'HPARAMS' section.